# Javascript add new <area> to <map> name

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a few map images, and I have the descriptions of the `map areas` in a database that I pulled out and made into an array. I am trying to have JavaScript perform a `Foreach $('area')`, and have it update lets say `var n` so that on each `area` when the tool tip displays it will have a different description, depending on that `areas` number. For example

```
<area shape="rect" coords="29,78,65,114" href="#">
```

will have the following description

```
<b>Taichi Pill Pack</b><br><br><span style='color:#ffcb4a'>This pack contains 100 Taichi Pills</span>
```

and so lets say that's the first `area`, the next one should have the following description

```
<b>Advanced Orb Bead Coupon</b><br><br><span style='color:#ffcb4a'>A valuable scroll that can be exchanged</span>
```

here is a snippet of the JavaScript for the tooltips

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var n = 0;
    $('area').each(function() {
        n++
    });
    $('area').qtip({
        content: {
            text: '<?php echo $desc[0]; ?>'
        },
        position: {
            my: 'top left',
            at: 'bottom right'
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-shadow qtip-rounded'
        }
    });
</script>
```

That will put all of the `area` elements with the same description.

Help is appreciated.

**Update**

---

@Pudge601 your answer gave the following output in the JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var desc = $.parseJSON('["<span style=\"color:#ffcb4a\">This pack contains 100 Taichi Pills, which will give<br>an amount of experience based on your current level.<br>Right-click to open.<br><br>Note: Only 10 of these items can be used per day.<br>Ascension LV1-149 characters can use up to 20\/day.<br>Ascension LV150+ characters can use up to 30\/day.<\/span>","Hey","You"]');
    $('area').each(function(n) {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: desc[n]
            },
            position: {
                my: 'top left',
                at: 'bottom right'
            },
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-shadow qtip-rounded'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The descriptions still didn't appear. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You should probably rather create a javascript array by looping your PHP array or convert it to JSON, which is basically the same result. Cause indeed your problem here is that the index of your PHP array never changes.

Comment: use loop to change the tool tip as you are playing with index 0 in php and try to add tooltip with loop only

Comment: Could you give an example or something to start me off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to bring all of the descriptions from the PHP into your JavaScript code through JSON. Then, you need to iterate over each of the areas creating a tooltip for each using the description at the current index. (Note that the `.each` function in JQuery does the indexes for you, so there's no need to manually define and increment `n`).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var desc = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($desc); ?>');
    $('area').each(function(n) {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: desc[n]
            },
            position: {
                my: 'top left',
                at: 'bottom right'
            },
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-shadow qtip-rounded'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This didn't work, as it didn't even display a tooltip

Comment: From the code that you've pasted being output, it looks it's probably an escaping issue with the quotation marks. May be easier simply to output the encoded array straight to a variable without parsing it as a JSON string, as in sabithpoocker's answer. Apart from that, this solution should work, I have a fiddle showing it as a working concept here: http://jsfiddle.net/dxUfK/. The position will be an issue though, since you're using the `area` element as the target for your qtip.

Comment: I was able to figure it out giving the last comment you said. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$js_array = json_encode($desc);
echo "var desc = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>

$('area').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).tooltip({title: desc[index]});
})
```

use `index` and `element` in jquery [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
Also use some method to make `php` array available in `js`

Comment: Sorry, i didnt notice the `<?php`